# Linking information in views with particular records in the HTML page

Tags: python, django

I have three models:

**Cars (containing records of the cars):**

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Sample records:

- Car A
- Car B
- Car C

**Features (containing a list with different features that may be of interest):**

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
primary_feature = models.BooleanField()
```

Sample records:

- Color, primary_feature = true
- Number of windows, primary_feature = false
- Owner, primary_feature = true

**CarFeatures (containing the features and their values):**

```
car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Sample records:

```
Car   | Feature | Value
==========================
Car A | color   | green
Car A | owner   | Alice
Car B | color   | blue
Car C | windows | 6
```

You may wonder about the structure of these models but I'm simplifying here. So let's assume these models make sense.

Now the question is: I want to pull up a list with all cars, and I then want to show *particular* features (those that are primary features) in the table. So my end goal is to get this:

```
Car   |   Color   |    Owner
=============================
Car A | green     | Alice
Car B | blue      | unknown
Car C | unknown   | unknown
```

It is important to note that not all features will be available for all cars.

The question is: if I want to get a list with *all* cars, and only *particular* features, what is the right way to go about it?

In the view I have this:

```
cars = Car.objects.all()
features = Feature.objects.filter(primary_feature=True)
car_features = CarFeature.objects.filter(feature__primary_feature=True)
```

On the HTML page I then do this:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <th>Car</th>
{% foreach feature in features %}
 <th>{{ feature.name }}</th>
{% endforeach %}
</tr>

{% foreach car in cars %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ car.name }}</td>
    {% foreach feature in features %}
      <td>??? How do I get the right value here??</td>
    {% endforeach %}
  </tr>
{% endforeach %}
</table>
```

This is what I get:

```
Car   |   Color   |    Owner
=============================
Car A | ???       | ???
Car B | ???       | ???
Car C | ???       | ???
```

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've not come across it yet, you may find the [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) useful for displaying objects in a table. For example you could do;

```
CarsList(ListView):
    model = Car

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['features'] = Feature.objects.filter(
            primary_feature=True
        )
        return context
```

Then in your template;

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Car</th>
        {% for feature in features %}
            <th>{{ feature.name }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>

{% for car in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ car.name }}</td>
        {% for car_feature in car.carfeatures_set.all %}
            <td>{{ car_feature.feature }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Now you've asked how to get all cars for a particular feature. That would involve a reverse lookup on the `CarFeature` objects which relate to the `Feature` you want.

For example;

```
special_feature = Features.objects.get(name='Special')

car_features = special_feature.carfeatures_set.all()

# Then all cars with `special_feature` is
special_cars = car_features.values('car')
```

Or in a template;

```
{% for car_feature in car_features %}
    {{ car_feature.car.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

You might find it beneficial to also read through the Many to One relationship docs; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

To show all the cars, with associated primary features you'd need to query the `CarFeatures` table similar to;

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CarList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    cars = list()
    for obj in Car.objects.all():
        cars.append(
            (obj.name,
             obj.carfeatures_set.filter(feature__primary_feature=True))
        )
    context['cars'] = cars
    return context
```

Which in the template would look like;

```
<h1>Cars</h1>
<ul>
{% for car, carfeatures in cars %}
    <li>
        {{ car }}
        <ul>
            {% for carfeature in carfeatures %}
                <li>{{ carfeature.feature.name }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, you write `you've asked how to get all cars for a particular feature` but that is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for how to get particular features for all cars. See the example which further clarifies it I hope.

Comment: So you want to loop over all cars, then show only the primary features of those cars?

Comment: Yes correct! But remember that some cars will have 0 primary features, others will have 5, etc. So somehow I want to make sure that I can still put the data in a table even though this list is not the same for each car (e.g. leaving the field empty when there is no record).

Comment: Ok, well I don't think your data structure will make this easy, but I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. However, in the proposed setup only the features will appear in the <ul> if they are present for the car. So a car with 1 feature will have 1 item; a car with 5 features will have 5 items. The difficulty is that I want to show this in a table format, in which all the features have fixed column positions. Any idea how that could be achieved?

Comment: You should adjust the queryset to get all the features, that can then give you an order (fixed position) based on the feature. Then you can display the associated car instead and output it all in table markup.

Comment: Will do. I'm trying to get it working based on your example. Is there any place in the manual where the thing you're doing in `get_context_data` is explained? I'm not sure what this is called or how to search for it.

Comment: Take a look at the Generic views, it's a method used fairly consistently to gather the context data to be used in the templates; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: OK I'm going to try and work this out, thanks a lot!